# Why Coq doesn't allow inversion, destruct, etc. when the goal is a Type?

Tags: coq, proof, inversion

When `refine`ing a program, I tried to end proof by `inversion` on a `False` hypothesis when **the goal was a `Type`**. Here is a reduced version of the proof I tried to do.

```coq
Lemma strange1: forall T:Type, 0>0 -> T.
  intros T H.
  inversion H.  (* Coq refuses inversion on 'H : 0 > 0' *)
```

Coq complained

```
Error: Inversion would require case analysis on sort 
Type which is not allowed for inductive definition le
```

However, since I do nothing with `T`, it shouldn't matter, ... or ?

I got rid of the `T` like this, and the proof went through:

```coq
Lemma ex_falso: forall T:Type, False -> T.
  inversion 1.
Qed.  

Lemma strange2: forall T:Type, 0>0 -> T.
  intros T H.
  apply ex_falso.  (* this changes the goal to 'False' *)
  inversion H.
Qed.
```

What is the reason Coq complained? Is it just a deficiency in `inversion`, `destruct`, etc. ?

Comment: An enlightening discussion at the coq-club mailing list: https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2014-12/msg00036.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had never seen this issue before, but it makes sense, although one could probably argue that it is a bug in `inversion`.

This problem is due to the fact that `inversion` is implemented by case analysis. In Coq's logic, one cannot *in general* perform case analysis on a *logical* hypothesis (i.e., something whose type is a `Prop`) if the result is something of computational nature (i.e., if the sort of the type of the thing being returned is a `Type`). One reason for this is that the designers of Coq wanted to make it possible to erase proof arguments from programs when extracting them into code in a sound way: thus, one is only allowed to do case analysis on a hypothesis to produce something computational if the thing being destructed cannot alter the result. This includes:

1. Propositions with no constructors, such as `False`.
2. Propositions with only one constructor, as long as that constructor takes no arguments of computational nature. This includes `True`, `Acc` (the accessibility predicated used for doing well-founded recursion), but excludes the existential quantifier `ex`.

As you noticed, however, it is possible to circumvent that rule by converting some proposition you want to use for producing your result to another one you can do case analysis on directly. Thus, if you have a contradictory assumption, like in your case, you can first use it to prove `False` (which is allowed, since `False` is a `Prop`), and *then* eliminating `False` to produce your result (which is allowed by the above rules).

In your example, `inversion` is being too conservative by giving up just because it cannot do case analysis on something of type `0 < 0` in that context. It is true that it can't do case analysis on it directly by the rules of the logic, as explained above; however, one could think of making a slightly smarter implementation of `inversion` that recognizes that we are eliminating a contradictory hypothesis and adds `False` as an intermediate step, just like you did. Unfortunately, it seems that we need to do this trick by hand to make it work.

Comment: Isn't the fact that ``<`` is in ``Prop`` so you can't case analyse it to build a ``Type`` the real issue ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Hmmm I guess I miss-interpreted your "bug in ``inversion``". I would call this a feature, to prevent universe inconsistency. Even if in this particular case the result of inversion is not used to compute the result, I'm glad that Coq prevents this kind of escalation. If the result does not depend on the inversion, do not perform it ;)

Comment: @Vinz how does this prevent universe inconsistency?

Comment: I don't remember the details, it's been a long time since I thought about this kind of issues. I'll try to dig up some old papers on the subject, and see if I can answer that :)

Comment: @Vinz regardless of consistency issues, inversion could still try to be smarter in that case without changing the basic logic -- I guess I was not very clear about that. It could do automatically what one would do by hand in this case, which is to produce a proof of `False` first.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Arthur's answer, there is a workaround using [constructive_definite_description](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Description.html#constructive_definite_description)  axiom. Using this axiom in a function would not allow to perform calculations and extract code from it, but it still could be used in other proofs:

```coq
From Coq Require Import Description.

Definition strange1: forall T:Type, 0>0 -> T.
  intros T H.
  assert (exists! t:T, True) as H0 by inversion H.
  apply constructive_definite_description in H0.
  destruct H0 as [x ?].
  exact x.
Defined.
```

Or same function without proof editing mode:

```coq
Definition strange2 (T: Type) (H: 0 > 0): T :=
  proj1_sig (constructive_definite_description (fun _ => True) ltac: (inversion H)).
```

Also there's a stronger axiom [constructive_indefinite_description](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/stdlib/Coq.Logic.IndefiniteDescription.html#constructive_indefinite_description) that converts a proposition `exists x:T, P x` (without uniqueness) into a corresponding sigma-type `{x:T | P x}`.