# What is required for Coq to generate an elimination combinator for an Inductive type?

Tags: coq

The Finite_sets library of Coq has an inductive type, specifying that some ensemble is finite:

```
Inductive Finite : Ensemble U -> Prop :=
| Empty_is_finite : Finite (Empty_set U)
| Union_is_finite :
  forall A:Ensemble U,
    Finite A -> forall x:U, ~ In U A x -> Finite (Add U A x).
```

I am trying to prove that membership in a finite set is decidable as follows:

```
Lemma Finite_dec (A:Type) : forall f:Ensemble A, Finite A f ->
  forall x:A, {In A f x} + {~In A f x}.
Proof.
intros.
induction H.
```

However, Coq produces the following error message:

```
Cannot find the elimination combinator Finite_rec, the
elimination of the inductive definition Finite on sort Set is
probably not allowed.
```

My question is, why is Coq not able to generate an elimination combinator for Finite? What is required of an inductive type for this to be possible?

Note: I need an elimination combinator for a different type, which is very similar to Finite, but do not know how to construct this.

Comment: In this case the particular problem is that the `Finite` inductive is of type prop, thus you cannot extract "true" information from it, which your decidability is. If you change your goal to `In A f x \/ ~In A f x` it will go throu.     You could obtain your result over different hypotheses but I would particularly use other approach altogether, namely encoding my finite sets as lists with a quotient.

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27324790/2747511) answer to a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322979/why-coq-doesnt-allow-inversion-destruct-etc-when-the-goal-is-a-type) Arthur Azevedo De Amorim perfectly explains the reason. Just replace `inversion` with `induction` in his explanation.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the sumbool to be able to use the lemma in a function which I am defining, so proving it only for propositions is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

One problem, as @ejgallego pointed out, is that you cannot do induction on something propositional, such as `Finite`, to obtain something computational such as `{P} + {~ P}`. There's a deeper issue, however: your result is not provable without assuming some form of the excluded middle, because it implies that all types have decidable equality.

```
Goal (forall (A : Type) (f : Ensemble A),
        Finite A f -> forall x, In A f x \/ ~ In A f x) ->
     forall (A : Type) (x y : A), x = y \/ x <> y.
Proof.
intros fin_dec A x y.
assert (fin : Finite A (Add A (Empty_set A) x)).
{ apply Union_is_finite.
  - apply Empty_is_finite.
  - intros []. }
specialize (fin_dec _ _ fin y).
destruct fin_dec as [H | H].
- destruct H.
  + destruct H.
  + destruct H. now left.
- right.
  contradict H. rewrite H. right. constructor.
Qed.
```

If you don't want to work with extra axioms, I would advise you to use lists instead of the ensemble library, and work with types that have decidable equality.

Comment: I realized the problem of decidable equality, but trying to prove this only for types with decidable equality still left me in a state where I couldn't prove the property. Though I could change to lists, as proposed above, I would still like to know if it would be possible to prove using something like Finite, even if only for types with decidable equality.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some things, I got some inspiration from one of the error messages

```
Elimination of an inductive object of sort Prop
is not allowed on a predicate in sort Type
because proofs can be eliminated only to build proofs
```

This gave me the inspiration of trying to change the return type from Prop to Type. In this case, I am capable of calling induction, and the proof of the following is straightforward.

```
Inductive Finite (U:Type) : Ensemble U -> Type :=
| Empty_is_finite : Finite U (Empty_set U)
| Union_is_finite :
  forall A:Ensemble U,
    Finite U A -> forall x:U, ~ In U A x -> Finite U (Add U A x).

Definition eq_dec (U:Type) : forall x y:U, {x=y} + {x<>y}.

Lemma Finite_dec (A:Type) : forall f:Ensemble A, Finite A f ->
  forall x:A, {In A f x} + {~In A f x}.
Proof.
intros.
induction X.
```

Though I do not fully understand the reasons for this.

Comment: [This](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/why-does-coq-have-prop) might clarify some things for you.